# Using @mixin or @function to change font sizes based on screen size

Tags: css

I am attempting to make my library of scss variables more responsive. Currently, I have several different font sizes that I would like to change based on the screen size. I would like to use a function or mixin to dynamically change the font size based on the screen size.

The code below is the basic idea. Insert a base size at a common screen width and get a responsive size out of it. However, I cannot return a value in a mixin and I cant use media queries in a function.

```
@function resize($size) {
 $result: $size;
 @media only screen and (max-width: $phone) {
   $result: $size * 0.75;
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: $tablet) {
   $result: $size * 0.75;
 }
 @media only screen and (max-width: $laptop) {
   $result: $size * 200;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: $desktop) {
   $result: $size * 0.75;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: $large-display) {
   $result: $size * 0.75;
 }
 @return $result
}
$h1-font-size: resize(1.5vmin) // outputs a size in the same unit that changes based on screen size
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this can help you.

```
$phone: 320px;    
$tablet: 500px;
$laptop: 1200px;
$desktop: 1400px;
$large-display: 1920px;

@mixin resize($size) {
      $result: $size;
        @media only screen and (max-width: $large-display){
          $result: $size * 2;
          font-size: $result;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: $desktop){
          $result: $size * 1.5;
          font-size: $result;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: $laptop){
          $result: $size * 1;
          font-size: $result;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: $tablet){
          $result: $size * .75;
          font-size: $result;
      }
        @media only screen and (max-width: $phone) {
          $result: $size * .5;
          font-size: $result;
        }
    }


h1 {
    @include resize(40px);
}
```